# Prove that a point $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$ iff $x$ is in $\overline{A\setminus{\{x}\}}$ in a Hausdorff topological space.

Tags: general-topology, limits

As the title says, I'm trying to answer a question which asks me to show that, for a non-empty subset $A$ of a Hausdorff topological space, a point $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$ (i.e. $x \in A'$) if and only if $x$ is in $\overline{A\setminus{\{x}\}}$.

I don't know how to go about doing this, so I'd really appreciate any help you could offer.

Comment: It's fine that you don't know how to solve this problem (that's why you're here, after all), and it's even fine that you don't know how a solution starts. However, I firmly believe that you have [some idea](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) on how to start solving the problem (that's not the same thing as how a solution starts).

Comment: Well, with the conditions mentioned, the propositionis not true. Just take the topological space $X$ which just has one point $x$. Then $\{\emptyset, X\}$ form a Hausdorff Topology and $x$ is an accumulation point of $A:=X$. However $A\backslash\{x\} = \emptyset $ is closed and $x$ is not a member of this closed set.

Comment: @Maxim $x$ is not an accumulation point of $A$ in that case, as there are neighbourhoods of $x$ whose intersection with $A$ is just $\{x\}$.

Comment: @Arthur: If accumulation point means that :in each open set  containing $x$ there is a member of $A$. But I admit: If you have a different definition then you will get to different conclusions.

Comment: @Maksim : You are defining an *adherent* point, not an *accumulation* point. Adherent points can be either accumulation points or isolated points. The closure of a set is the set of its adherent points.

Comment: Hausdorffness seems redundant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Hausdorffness is redundant. I'm using the definition that $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$ if and only if every neighborhood of $x$ contains an element of $A$ different from $x$.

Consider $x \in A'$ and suppose that $x \not\in\overline{A\setminus{\{x}\}}$. Then, we can find a closed set $F$ such that $A\setminus\{x\} \subseteq F$ but $x \not\in F$. So, $F^c$ is an open set containing $x$ such that $F^c \cap \left( A\setminus\{x\}\right)=\emptyset$. Contradiction.

Conversely, suppose that $x \in \overline{A\setminus{\{x}\}}$ but $x\not\in A'$. Hence, there exists an open set $U$ such that $x \in U$ but $U \cap \left( A\setminus\{x\}\right) = \emptyset$. This means that we have found a closed set $U^c$ such that $A-\{x\}\subseteq U^c$. Hence, $\overline{A\setminus{\{x}\}} \subseteq U^c$ by definition of closure. But since $x \in \overline{A\setminus{\{x}\}}$, we have that $x\in U^c$. Contradiction.